# Bad Etiquette or Smart Poker?

Tags: cash-game, etiquette, casino

When you're sitting at a cash table at a casino and you're ready to leave, is it bad etiquette to wait until you're about to be in the big blind and then walk? This obviously makes the most sense because you may as well sit and see some free cards.
I've always done this, but last time I was at a new poker room, I got a couple of snide comments for pulling this.
So what's the consensus among you guys?

Comment: Not bad form in my eyes, or any player I know. Be aware though, if you have announced you are leaving or started racking your chips and you stop and play a hand, it's a pretty strong tell you have big cards.

Comment: @LaconicDroid and therefore often a good spot to run a bluff as a parting blow. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not bad form in my opinion and I've never seen anyone berated for doing so in the way you described.

I also usually do this, for the reasons you have given, and will continue to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You would be stupid not to.

When you sit if you have to pay a bb to play or wait for the bb to play then all is fair.

If you don't have to pay a bb to sit then shame on them.